Pullback on $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$-coefficient group cohomology from connected compact Lie group to its maximal torus is injective?
For $G$ a Lie group (or topological group) with classifying space $BG$, for $A$ a commutative ring, let us denote by $H_G^*(A) = H^*(BG;A)$ the group cohomology ring of $G$ with coefficients in $A$; it is the ordinary $A$-coefficient cohomology ring of the classifying space $BG$.

In what follows, let $G$ be a compact connected real Lie group, and let $T \subset G$ be a maximal torus.
My question is:

If $A \in \{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$, then is the pullback homomorphism $H_G^*(A) \rightarrow H_T^*(A)$ injective?

If yes, would anyone have a hint or reference suggestion describing how this is shown?

My motivation for considering this question is from this paper ("The index of elliptic operators, III") of Atiyah and Singer: the statement (1.2) says if $A \in \{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ then the
pullback homomorphism $H_G^*(A) \rightarrow H_T^*(A)$ identifies the domain with a particular subset of the codomain (namely the subset fixed by the action of the Weyl group), which would seem to require the homomorphism to be injective.

The answer is yes. You can find a proof at the beginning of May's "A Note on the Splitting Principle."

@BenSteffan Thank you very much!

Following the notes suggested in the comments, if I'm not mistaken, we can see the desired result holds more generally when $A$ is any commutative ring "in which $p$ is invertible for every prime $p$ such that $H_*(G;\mathbb{Z})$ has $p$-torsion". In particular this condition is satisfied when $A$ is any field of characteristic 0, regardless of $G$.
